# Kotlin - Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead

Tags: java, android, generics, sharedpreferences, kotlin

I have a simple helper function to get value from SharedPreferences like this :

```
operator inline fun <reified T : Any> SharedPreferences.get(key: String, defaultValue: T? = null): T? {
    return when (T::class) {
        String::class -> getString(key, defaultValue as? String) as T?
        Int::class -> getInt(key, defaultValue as? Int ?: -1) as T?
        Boolean::class -> getBoolean(key, defaultValue as? Boolean ?: false) as T?
        Float::class -> getFloat(key, defaultValue as? Float ?: -1f) as T?
        Long::class -> getLong(key, defaultValue as? Long ?: -1) as T?
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

I have used reified type parameter to have switching over class type and since it is an operator function, I should be able to call with the square brackets syntax like below :

```
val name: String? = prefs[Constants.PREF_NAME]
```

But, every time I call it,  UnsupportedOperationException is thrown indicating  function is not able to get class type.

When I attach debugger and evaluate `T::class`, It is giving me an error `"Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead."`

What's wrong with my function? I could not catch the mistake. can anyone help?

Edit : The whole class is [here](https://gist.github.com/krupalshah/782c42c70f2c58004c9bbda6291315e6) and [this is where](https://gist.github.com/krupalshah/d091be195999a7ddf52c3bb0f04f2bf3) I get the error.

**Update:** It seems to be Kotlin compiler issue. 
Track https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17748 and
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17748 for updates.

Comment: I can not reproduce your error. One thing I can note is that you're not returning the result of `when`, so it will always return null.

Comment: @JornVernee can you please see this : https://gist.github.com/krupalshah/782c42c70f2c58004c9bbda6291315e6 I need your help.

Comment: I can not help you if I can not reproduce the error.

Comment: @JornVernee I have this activity which reproduces the error https://gist.github.com/krupalshah/fc758c054c3042d66a703cc6896d75ee

Comment: @JornVernee Here is the simplified version of it : https://gist.github.com/krupalshah/d091be195999a7ddf52c3bb0f04f2bf3 I get UnsupportedOperationException every time

Comment: I don't have Android. This looks like a compiler error, but I can't reproduce it with the compiler I have.

Comment: With that gist I was able to reproduce the problem, but it's with the line `val age: Int? = prefs[Constants.PREF_AGE, 23]`, not the one you have in the question.

Comment: Here is my MCVE if you want to use it: https://gist.github.com/JornVernee/34e2c9dce310ecea369efd415b1ee670

Comment: @JornVernee Ok....so function is working working fine then couldn't catch the error. Error is at runtime and so hard to catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is curious, but it seems that `Int::class` is not the same as `Int?::class` (which is an illegal expression any ways).

When you add the line:

```
println(T::class)
```

To the `get` method, and call `val age: Int? = prefs["AGE", 23]`, you will see that it prints `java.lang.Integer`.

It seems like `Int?` is translated into `java.lang.Integer`.

A possible (but imho kind of hacky) solution is to use the references to Java classes as the cases for when:

```
operator inline fun <reified T : Any> get(key: String, defaultValue: T? = null): T? {
    return when (T::class) {
        String::class -> getString(key, defaultValue as? String) as T?
        java.lang.Integer::class -> getInt(key, defaultValue as? Int ?: -1) as T?
        java.lang.Boolean::class -> getBoolean(key, defaultValue as? Boolean ?: false) as T?
        java.lang.Float::class -> getFloat(key, defaultValue as? Float ?: -1f) as T?
        java.lang.Long::class -> getLong(key, defaultValue as? Long ?: -1) as T?
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. First solution is also working fine now. Did we discover new bug in Kotlin compiler?

Comment: @KrupalShah Not a bug, maybe a shortcoming; that It doesn't have special treatment when comparing `java.lang.Integer::class` to `Int::class`

Comment: Hm.. ok. Your second solution is fine but the only problem is that I should be able to pass null as default value even if I want String. That time it won't work.

Comment: @KrupalShah Oh yeah, I didn't think about that